# System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred

Tags: xamarin.ios, apigee

While trying to test out Apigee for our app, I ran into the error "System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred." I think that it is caused by one of two things which the output showed;

- Loaded assembly: /Users/magnimbusllc/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ApigeeTestApp/69798d35-5a45-4499-9fcb-2029fc7d533c/assemblies/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  2014-01-15 12:09:12.391 ApigeeTestApp[65077:a0b] Could not load 'Newtonsoft.Json' for registration: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:351 
  at MonoTouch.Registrar.OldDynamicRegistrar.RegisterAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly a) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/OldDynamicRegistrar.cs:67
- objc[65077]: Class AXEmojiUtilities is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libAXSpeechManager.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I have a [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/Cysc0sYL) with the full output from building. I just don't know if I should rebuild the Apigee Library using a different Newtonsoft library or if it is something else (don't fully understand the error).

I am building an iOS app using Xamarin, the machines I am using are a Windows 8 machine for development, and a Mac Mini for building.

Comment: Are you trying to use Apigee App Services/Usergrid?  If so, which SDK are you using?  Are you trying to create an iOS application?  Are you on a Mac or Windows PC?

Comment: @MikeMalloy Using Xamarin iOS on a Windows 8 machine, updated question to include that. And yeah using Apigee App services.

Answer (score 0):

As this looks to be a .NET application, you might want to try to unload the dependency (Newtonsoft.Json.dll) and re-add it in Visual Studio.

Another approach is to compile NewtonSoft yourself, as it is open-source.